# Can anyone suggest a book on Fourier Analysis containing many good problems

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, book-recommendation

I am taking a basic course in Fourier Analysis in my undergrad Analysis class and I know the theory and related theorems. However, this is a relatively new zone for me and I would like a book that contains many good problems (solved/unsolved). I have been currently reading Rudin but its major problem is that there is practically no solved example.

What I want is a book/pdf that has many problems which will help strengthen my mathematical stronghold on the subject. Please note that I am not a physics student: I am essentially a pure maths student.

Thank you!!

Comment: Exercises in Fourier Analysis by Korner might be a good start

Answer (score 1):

I used Katznelson "[An Introduction to Harmonic Analysis](http://books.google.com/books/about/An_Introduction_to_Harmonic_Analysis.html?id=gkpUE_m5vvsC)". It is a standard text on Fourier Series and Harmonic Analysis, with a set of good exercises after each section. It has been updated to cover even more topics since I used it 34 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Analysis by Lieb and Loss, Chapter 5, its easier to read than most fourier analysis texts.

Rudin is pretty much a standard text though.

Comment: Actually, as I mentioned, I am not in search for texts on Fourier Analysis. I am looking for problems on the subjects. Good exercises, to be precise. Which Rudin has totally shifted to the last of its chapter.

Comment: There are basic exercises at the end of chapter 5

Comment: Okay. Will go through it then.

Comment: Do you fully understand $L_p$ spaces?

Comment: No I have not studied those.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22426/discussion-between-sandstone-and-yedaynara).

Answer (score 0):

You can try Fourier Analysis by Stein and Shakarchi

Answer (score 0):

If you're so proudly a pure mathematics student-which is self-defeatingly narrow in my opinion, but ok-you might want to bypass Fourier analysis in favor of the general subject of abstract harmonic analysis, for which Fourier analysis is a special case. The classic textbooks in this regard are Katznelson, Loomis and the more recent one by Folland. There's also the overview volume by Krantz and the books that take a real analysis perspective, such as Stein and Torchinsky.

Comment: I really should get Krantz's book since I took many classes from him while I was an undergrad. This included a course in which we used Katznelson. He is an excellent teacher; he even got voted the teacher of the year at UCLA, which is almost unheard of for a math professor.

Comment: @robjohn I'm a fan of Krantz's books-he,of course,has spent most of his career at the University of Washington at St.Louis.

Comment: Yes, but before that, he was at UCLA for at least a couple of years while I was an undergrad, from 1977-1981.

Answer (score 0):

I got this book: [*Fourier Series*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486633179) since it was really cheap. Haven't read through it yet, but it has great reviews.